# Is there a way to have an event without date?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

My use case is that I have an event with limited capacity but we expect it to be oversubscribed and that we will repeat it. The waitlist feature allows me to collect extra participants very nicely. But there will also be people who are interested but can't make the specific date and I would like to capture these. I know I can have a separate form for them to register their interest and collect them in a group, but I'd prefer to collect them as participants. Ideally, I'd do that with a different participant status ("Interested") but I don't think there is a way to do that. A second event would be fine, but I can't give it a date at this stage.

I'm using WordPress so the fancy form features of Drupal are not available.

Notes on petednz's answer:
I used a radio option in the price field for registration or just interest, but it counted both options towards the event participant count even though I set the interest option not to count. Also when the waitlist is activated then the price set doesn't show so I can't distinguish between wanting to be on the waitlist and interest in future events That means I can't use the waitlist for two reasons, but I can live with that and deal with the waitlist that from my interest list manually. But when I set the registration option to my maximum number of attendees, I got this error when I tried to book for another so wasn't allowed to continue registering interest. Is this a bug? Using CiviCRM version 5.35.1 on WordPress.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function freeze() on
> string in
> /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php:209
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php(439):
> CRM_Price_BAO_PriceField::freezeIfEnabled('<span class="cr...', Array)
> #1 /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php(627):
> CRM_Price_BAO_PriceField::addQuickFormElement(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register),
> 'price_48', '48', false, '0', 'Choice', Array, Array) #2
> /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php(400):
> CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register::buildAmount(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register))
> #3 /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.p
> in
> /home/customer/www/staging10.crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php
> on line 209

Comment: you might want to see if you can replicate a simplified version on the wp civicrm demo site

Comment: Tried that (Wordpress demo which 5.40 alpha1 and it worked for a maximum number of attendees for the actual registration option, so there must be a bug in my version. Will investigate. Still can't use the waitlist though, but that's OK.

Comment: It is a bug dev/event#53: 20073 which is fixed in CiviCRM 5.37.0

Answer (score 2):

If you use a civi Price Set, you can indeed set an option on there to not count towards your Participant Count which i think can therefore deliver what you need

Comment: Good idea and this almost does what I need, but it doesn't quite work as I interpret the documentation and also triggers a fatal error. See note added to the question as it won't fit here.